# Detect bottom of the document onscroll with JS

Tags: javascript

Having hard time detecting bottom of the document. Trying the following code:

```
let bottomOfWindow = document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight === document.documentElement.offsetHeight
```

Then if it's `true` i'm firing my custom function. But it's never true, because it can't be 100% equal, because:

```
console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight + ' and document height is ' + document.documentElement.offsetHeight)
```

often gives such results: "3197.199951171875 and document height is 3198" and as you can see it's not equal, so my function won't fire. `Math.round()` won't help in my case. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your comparison:

```
let bottomOfWindow = document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight > document.documentElement.offsetHeight -1;
```

Comment: In my case, `document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight` is always lower than `document.documentElement.offsetHeight` by small amount.

Comment: That's why I added the `-1` at the end

Comment: It feels a bit hacky, but it works. Isn't there a better way to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is another solution, but I don't see why this seems hacky... Unit offsets are all used all over the place for edge cases like this. Sometimes that unit of buffer is necessary. It would be hacky to me if it was anything other than 1, but a unit of buffer is practically standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect if the document is scrolled to the bottom like this:

```
if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    //at the bottom of the page
}
```

Demo:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
    if(window.pageYOffset==0){
      alert('At the top of the page');
    }
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset ) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        alert("At the bottom of the page.");
    }
});
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 3000px;
}
```

On Macs, there is a problem with a small offset (about 1px), so we can modify the check to subtract 2 from the body's offsetHeight.

```
if(window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset >= document.body.offsetHeight - 2){
//at the bottom of the page
}
```

Comment: It has the same issue as my variant.